# How to Input Domain and Then Use Info in an iFrame on Same or New Page

Tags: javascript, iframe, submit-button

I would like to be able to allow a user to input their web address and then use the address in an iframe.

The address will be placed here:

```
<iframe src="http://blahblahblah/blah/?blah=WEB_ADDRESS_FROM_USER_INPUT/&x=63&y=36" id="my-iframe" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I've tried finding the answer all over the place, but I'm having no luck.

Thanks for any help you can provide to this newb.

Answer (score 0):

I develop it for about six years^^. Here my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function aendereInhalt()
 {
  var adresse1;
  adresse1 = prompt("Bitte geben sie die Adresse ein");
  if (adresse1 != null && adresse1 != "")
  {
    if (adresse1.indexOf("http:\/\/") == -1)
    {
        adresse1 = "http:\/\/" + adresse1;
        //this is nessecary, because in IE it does not work without protocol
    }
    document.getElementById("myIframe1").src =  adresse1;
  }
 }
</script>
<body>
    <iframe src="" id="myIframe1" style="width: 50%; height: 99%;"></iframe>
    <a href="" onClick="aendereInhalt(); return false;">Display content</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This **example** opens a prompt input field, so the user can enter an URL.